# Why Fragment SupportMapFragment has not been attached yet

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I'm trying to implement supportmapfragment on my fragment but for some reason it gives me error. What I'm doing wrong?

Error I'm getting:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SupportMapFragment{67446a6} (09078183-572b-41c6-8795-7441157371d5) has not been attached yet.

supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this). Is never called it crash before that

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

    val supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment()
    supportMapFragment.childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.google_map)
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    return view
   }
}
```

And fragment_map .xml file looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primaryBackground"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


       <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
private lateinit var mapFragment: SupportMapFragment
```

removing

```
val supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment()
```

and changing

```
supportMapFragment.childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.google_map)
```

to

```
mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.google_map) as SupportMapFragment
```

fixes this